# ambiguity with conversion operator and constructor

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I am learning c++, faced a problem with conversion operator. I am creating a complex class that can do basic operations on complex number.

```
class complex
{
    double real, img;

public:
    complex(double re=0,double im=0){
        real = re;
        img = im;
    }
    double get_real() const{
        return real;
    }
    double get_img() const{
        return img;
    }

};
```

I overloaded + operator:

```
complex operator+(complex a,complex b){
    return complex(a.get_real()+b.get_real(),a.get_img()+b.get_img());
}
```

With this code addition with double/integer with complex number works fine because of the constructor.

```
complex a(2,4);
complex b = 1+a;
```

But when I use a conversion operator inside the class

```
operator int(){
    int re = real;
    return re;
}
```

Addition with double/int stooped working

```
b = 1 + a;
// ambiguous overload
```

This seems weird, can anyone please explain how adding the conversion operator is creating this ambiguity?
I could not find any resource online.

Comment: Could you [edit]  your question and transform your code snippets into a [MCVE].

Comment: Your edit just made it worse. Read this carefully: [mcve].

Comment: i apologize.
is it okay now?
only the necessary portions are kept. should i bring them in a single block?

Comment: You didn't read this: [mcve], did you? Summary: Your code should me minimal (strip anything not useful), complete (don't strip too much, the code still needs to compile), and it should be something users can copy/paste/compile and run and reproduce your problem on their computers. _"should i bring them in a single block?"__ yes

Comment: i wasn't sure about the whole copy paste thing
thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression statement

```
b = 1 + a;
```

either the operand `1` can be converted to the type complex using the conversion constructor or the object a can be converted to the type int using the conversion operator.

So there is an ambiguity between two binary operators +: either the built-in operator for the type int can be used or the user-defined operator for the type complex can be used.

To avoid the ambiguity you could for example declare the conversion operator as explicit.

```
 explicit operator int() const {
        int re = real;
        return re;
    }
```